# How to overcome the problem of duplicates in Panel data

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkiYx.png)here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Osm.png)
I tried to convert my data to panel data but i kept experiencing an error message. The data is in the form of likert scale. The error message was

> duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame  to find out
> which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")

Also, i would like to conduct a probit and logit model with my data.

My data frame does not include duplicates but R Studio is assuming that they are duplicates. I do not want to remove any of my data. Can someone advise me on how to resolve the issue?. Or is there any way that i can make all my values unique without removing any of them?

Here are the functions that i used before trying to convert my data to panel data;

```
library(readxl)
sample <- read_excel("Documents/sample.xlsx")
View(sample)
pdata.frame(sample)
```

I was trying to convert my data to panel data but it did not work.

country 1   1   1   1   1
year    1   1   1   1   1
age    1   2   1   1   3
health  2   3   2   2   1
schooling 1 0   1   2   0

Comment: Can you `dput` the data? It will give a better chance to get an answer if we can actually have it.

Comment: I have added an image of the data above